# Using -i option causes Python to NOT search CWD (ie no '' in path)

Tags: python, cygwin, sys.path

I have an issue that I found very strange.

Why would invoking Python with '-i' option affect sys.path?

I have two aliases that I use to launch Python:

```
alias p='python3 '
alias pr='python3 -i ~/.pythonrc'
```

When I use the latter, sys.path does not include '' at the beginning so I cannot load modules from the CWD.

```
$ pr
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['/home/x', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
>>>
```

if I add '' to sys.path it works fine:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0,'')
>>> import koop_db
>>>
```

Also, if I call it without the -i option it works fine:

```
$ p
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 20 2022, 21:37:52)
[GCC 11.2.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
>>>
```

Does anyone have any idea why it would be designed this way?

Is this a bug or a "feature"?

Comment: OK, I see in the sys.path that the path to the file included on the command line replaces the current working directory in sys.path.    also found this: 
  https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/759

Comment: Here is another discussion that might help others confused by the default behavior:

https://python-forum.io/thread-38041-post-160964.html#pid160964

Comment: Are you normally using the variable `PYTHONSTARTUP`? If you use `-i`, the file mentioned in this environment variable won't be loaded.

Comment: I am not using PYTHONSTARTUP although I'd be curious to know if it would have behaved more like I originally expected if I had used it rather than -i and a file.  And it is no big deal to add the current directory (via an empty string) to sys.path.   I just found it strange that the CWD is specifically mentioned in the docs under modules as being in the search path, and it somewhat surreptitiously gets pulled when executing a file.   I can see reasons for it though.   Maybe add it to the module docs if it is not there already?